# Bulk insert.update in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Currently in my MongoDB collection I have this data

```
currentDataList = [{'id':1,'name':test1},{'id':2,'name':test2}]
```

but now I have a new data list with huge amount of data like

```
newDataList = [{'id':1,'name':a1},{'id':2,'name':a2},{'id':3,'name':a3}.....{'id':9999,'name':a9999}]
```

and I need to update this newDataList in my collection with **insert if not exist/update if exist** manner.

I do not want to update the documents one by one because it will take time.

Can anyone please suggest some solution for bulk insert/update in this case.

Comment: Use `upsert` and bundle all of the requests together in a bulk write operation?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update in bulk:

If you want to update in bulk you can use [`db.runCommand()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) with `update` command.

**Command example:**

```
db.runCommand({
    update: "collectionName",
    updates: [
      {
        q: { id: 3 },
        u: { $set: { id: 3, name: "a3", newFields: "newField" } },
        multi: true,
        upsert: true
      },                          // the list goes here
      {
        q: { id: 11 },
        u: { $set: { id: 11, name: "a11" } },
        multi: true,
        upsert: true
      }
    ],
    ordered: false,
    writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 }
  });
```

#### Update one by one:

Alternately you can run the  query for each item in the list using the [`.update()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#using-upsert-with-multi--match-) method with `upsert` set to `true`.

[mongodb playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qBl7VcWdu-C)

operation example:

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 3
},
{
  $set: {
    id: 3,
    name: "a3",
    newField: "newField",
    
  }
},
{
  upsert: true,
  multi: true
})
```

Comment: But this is to update documents one by one....Is there any way to update in bulk??

Comment: @RahulGupta I have updated the answer to include update in bulk method.